# TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given) How to resolve?

Tags: python

Hey thank you for taking the time to help me out, I'll cut straight to the point:
This is just a small project I've started to practice my Python skills before my GCSE the current issue I'm having is appending a number to a list as I have gone through each part of the program I've managed to resolve all current issues, however, I have been unable to resolve this issue all/any feedback concerning this issue/ making the program more efficient would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
##code##
name = input("hello user what is your name?")
print("thank you for using our program:",name.title(),)
userchoice = input("which program would you like to use: add numbers,minus 
numbers, alphabetical word order?")
#add numbers#
numList = []
addnewnumber = input ("would you like to add a new number?")
while addnewnumber == 'yes':
    newnumber = input("what is your number?")
    numList.append()
if addnewnumber == 'no':
    numListsum = sum(numList)
    print (numListsum)

 ##Console message##
RESTART: C:/Users/SWILS/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python 
coding/1.0.py 
hello user what is your name?sean
thank you for using our program: Sean
which program would you like to use: add numbers,minus numbers, alphabetical 
word order?add numbers
would you like to add a new number?yes
what is your number?6
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/SWILS/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python 
coding/1.0.py", line 11, in <module>
numList.append()
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Comment: What did you mean to accomplish with the line `numList.append()`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: just *read* the error message carefully next time!

Comment: `numList.append()`: append *what*?

Comment: `.append` takes an 'argument', which is what you want to append to it. Maybe you wanted to do `numList.append(newNum)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `numList.append()` must have a paramter.
So , change to this `numList.append(newnumber)`.

Answer (score 16):

this works for me -- >

```
append((item1 , item2))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I'm curious what this answer provides that the [accepted answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45845246/3987854) doesn't already provide. Yes, you can add tuples to the list with `append()`, but that is unlikely to be the case in this example, as the user prompted to enter *one* number.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means exactly what it says: `.append()` expects you to pass one parameter, but you've actually passed no parameters. Try this:

```
numList.append(newnumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is like this:

```
numList = []
addnewnumber = input ("would you like to add a new number?")
while addnewnumber == 'yes':
    newnumber = input("what is your number?")
    numList.append(newnumber)
```

The problem was that you needed to pass a value to the `append` method of `numList`, for it to append.

Answer (score 0):

- actually append something inside the `append` function
- fix the while loop

code updated to do what you want:

```
name = input("hello user what is your name?")
print("thank you for using our program:",name.title(),)
userchoice = input("which program would you like to use: add numbers,minus 
numbers, alphabetical word order?")
#add numbers#
numList = []
addnewnumber = input ("would you like to add a new number?")
while addnewnumber == 'yes':
    newnumber = input("what is your number?")
    numList.append(newnumber)
    addnewnumber = input ("would you like to add a new number?")
numListsum = sum(numList)
print (numListsum)
```